# Java SQL: Error before result set

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I'm having a problem with a query in my java application. It's a simple query to get a users score based on their name, however, I am constantly getting an error and can't spot where the problem is coming from.

```
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";    
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, USERNAME, PASSWORD);   
        st  = con.createStatement();


        PreparedStatement preStatement = con.prepareStatement("select score from playerscore where name=?");
        preStatement.setString(1, "tomcat");

        ResultSet resultSet = preStatement.executeQuery();
        score               = resultSet.getInt(1);
```

Could someone cast an eye and point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Image of stack trace

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/stackr.jpg/

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace? It would be helpful.

Comment: added link to image of stacktrace

Comment: A side note: do not write .newInstance() where you have written it. Class.forName(...) is enough and this will just create an unnecessary instance of the driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially, the `ResultSet` is positioned *before* the first row. Therefore, you must first call `resultSet.next()` to move to the first row, before you can retrieve any of its values.

You can verify if the first row is indeed present by checking the returned `boolean` of `resultSet.next()`.